# MagicalRecord saveWithBlock issue

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

The one thing that I want to achieve - detect when all entities are created and represent it in my table.

As i understood correct the completion block for the code below will be invoked when all core data entries will be created? am I right? Because when I try to findAll entities in another controller I expected that all entries are created. But findAll return empty array. Only reload controller solve this issue.

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    NSArray *objects = responseData[@"data"];

    NSArray *array = [Team MR_importFromArray:objects inContext:localContext];

} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    operationSuccess(nil); // return me to controller that requested this block
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in the 2.2 release of magical record that doesn't seem to save imports. Trying using version 2.1.

Comment: We've done a lot of work to the data import code for the 2.3 release — could you please give that a try and see if the issue is resolved? If not, point me at the issue for this on the issue tracker and I'll have a look at fixing it. Thanks!

Comment: @TonyArnold: I'm using version `2.3.2` and still getting this issue. Any idea? I'd like to mention that I'm using in Swift project.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, try this:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    for(NSDictionary *dictionary in objects) {
        [Team  MR_importFromObject:dictionary inContext:localContext];
    }
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[Team MR_findAll]];
    operationSuccess(array);
}
```

There's a known issue with **saveWithBlock** and **importFromArray** where the completion block is fired before all the data is saved (thus why you're not seeing them returned right away - see https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/642#issuecomment-40002145). By iterating through your array with **importFromObject:inContext**: you're guaranteed that your completion block will only be called after all saves are done.